# Laravel spatie medialibrary upload not works with suPHP on server

Tags: php, laravel

I have followed this [instruction](https://appdividend.com/2018/06/02/laravel-avatar-image-upload-tutorial-with-example/) to enable users to upload avatar image.

It works perfectly on local. But when I uploaded code to server it does not work.

When I made *public* folder permission to *777*, I get a 500 error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you created a symlink to public storage directory by using `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: You can check the ".error_log" file over the server to understand the problem

Comment: the same problem, the media folder is created has 700 permission but it must be 755 to show. no need to storage:link because the media file system is defined.